# Canonical 'simple project' makefile

Tags: makefile

Your small C/C++ project has reached a point where it's no longer practical to have all your code in one file. You want to split out a few components. So you make a `src/` directory, and then... you have to write a real Makefile. Something more than `hello: hello.o`. Uh-oh... was it `$@` or `$<` or `$^`? Crap. You don't remember (I never do).

Do you have a 'one-size fits all' simple Makefile that can deal with straightforward source trees? If so, what's in it and why? I'm looking for the smallest, simplest Makefile that can compile a directory full of C files nicely without me having to edit the Makefile every time I add a file. Here's what I have so far:

```
CXX = clang++
CXXFLAGS = ...
LDFLAGS = ...
EXENAME = main

SRCS = $(wildcard src/*.cc)
OBJS = $(patsubst src%.cc,build%.o, $(SRCS))

all: $(EXENAME)

build/%.o: src/%.cc
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS)

$(EXENAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) 

clean:
    rm -rf $(EXENAME) build/
```

This Makefile builds all the `.cc` files in the `src/` directory into `.o` files in the `build/` directory, then links them up into the parent directory.

What would you do differently?

Comment: I'd use cmake. Maintaining a Makefile directly just doesn't scale up at all once you have a couple of header files. Autotools are _way_ to bulky and require too many steps. Cmake is a true one-size-fits-all tool.

Comment: I would definitely use cmake for anything more than ~10 files; it just seems a little heavy for things smaller than that.

Comment: It's surprisingly unheavy, and it really just does exactly the necessary amount of work. After the first invocation, you just keep calling `make`, even if you change the CMake file -- there's just so much magic in the way it figures out the dependencies :-) (But yes, it does create a bit of a directory structure which you might find too much for too small situations.)

Comment: What's the point of this question? "I'll show you mine, if you show me yours"? Do you have any particular problem?

Comment: @eriktous I'm looking for a decent solution to the problem of building a directory full of C files. I feel like it can be done better than how I did it.

Comment: I'd say, if this currently works for you than you already have a decent solution. Just work with it until you encounter a situation that gives a real problem, and then make the required changes. Personally, over the last year or so, I've expanded my own makefile template for small projects to over 200 lines. I can drop it in, only have to enter the name of the program, and it automatically collects all source files in the src/ directory (C, C++, and/or Fortran), creates dependencies, and builds the program. I still think things can be done better, and keep changing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reconsider you decision not to have an explicit list of sources-- I think it may cause you trouble in the long run. But if that's your decision, this makefile is pretty good.

In the `%.o` rule I would use `$<` instead of `$^`, so that later you can add dependencies like

```
build/foo.o: bar.h
```

And when you're ready, you can take a look at [Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html).

Comment: why might that cause me trouble?

Comment: @nornagon: it's often useful to have two (or more) different executables that have some code in common. Keeping the non-common code untangled will require either explicit source lists in the makefile(s), or a directory structure that mirrors the dependency graph-- the former is usually easier. But if you ever run into this problem it's easy to shift from one scheme to the other.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used CMake, so I really can't say anything about that.  The best that I can offer is a program that we have at school called 'makemake', which automatically makes Makefiles - http://www.cs.rit.edu/~swm/makemake/  It's not a very advanced program, but it gets the job done.  On the plus side, it's incredibly easy to use - simply do 'makemake > Makefile' in the directory and you have a Makefile which will build and link all the source files in that directory(C and C++).  On the bright side, if you ever add more files, you just run makemake again and you have a new makefile.  On the downside, there's no way to keep any custom targets that you've done from one generated makefile to the next.

As for 'one size fits all' makefiles, while you could definitely do that, it takes away from the purpose of the 'make' command in the first place - which is to keep track of the files last modified time, and thus only re-compile the files that have recently changed, or depend on header files that have just changed(although to generate the correct you can use 'makedepend' - http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/makedepend.1.html ).  You could use what you currently have plus makedepend in order to make a self-updating makefile.

Answer (score -1):

Use automake tools. Its easy to make changes and less burden to the developer. Its as simple as specifying the SOURCES, LDLIBS, LDFLAGS as variables. At first it may seem like a bit weird. But it becomes your favorite as you do more on it.

Comment: I hate autotools with a vengeance. Also, it is *way* overkill for a 6-file project.

Comment: I hate autotools because most of the time, I end up having more SLOC in autotools' *generated* files than SLOC in my program itself. That's utterly imbalanced and ridiculous.